# Crontab : dump of mysql database and tar it

Tags: cron, mysql, tar

I have created a cron to save my mysql database :

> 36 11 * * * mysqldump -u root -p myDataBase  >$HOME/myDatabase.sql

Now I would like to tar this sql file, do I need to create another cron job?
 Can I concatenate both jobs?

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this would be instead of running the sqldump command in Cron you can create a shell script and execute that script in cron job. This way you will have flexibility to create a tar as well once the dump is successfully completed. You can add a script for eg at /opt/cronjob/sqldump.sh Make sure your script is executable.

```
    #!/bin/sh
    mysqldump -u root -p myDataBase >$HOME/myDatabase.sql
    #Tar creation command goes here
```

Then you can modify your cron job as follows.

```
36 11 * * * /opt/cronjob/sqldump.sh 2>&1 >> /var/log/cron.log
```

In case cron doesn't run as expected you can check the output at /var/mail/mail

Also you can run multiple commands in Cron job itself by using && to seperate two commands.

Comment: Nothing happens, I have an empty folder /var/mail, but not a var/mail/mail

Comment: For simple testing i would replace the command with something simple like ls and see if it's running and also change the job to run every minute for testing. Also what OS are you using? Please share more details like you are able to see your cron job under "crontab -e"